# Laravel Homestead serves outdated views

Tags: nginx, laravel-4, php

I'm using Homestead for Laravel development, but I'm currently experiencing some caching problems. When I change a view the changes are propagated to the server but Nginx still serves the old version?

I already tried restarting Nginx, PHP5-FPM and even tried re-installing Homestead. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Is OPCache enabled ? I've had the same issue with the views being cached and changes not being applied.

Comment: For some reason OPCache was enabled. Disabling it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by OPCache, once disabled everything works fine again.